# C++ - Concat 2 Long long bytes

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and I'm learning bit shifting.

Suppose I have 2 long long bytes given

long long bytes1 = b11111111; long long bytes2 = b10000000;

long long result;

I want to concat the 2 bytes so that the result variable will hold: = 1000000011111111

Is there a way on how to concat this in my specific order of bytes?

Comment: Any [good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would have told you how to use the bitwise operators. Please read a book, then come back here and update your question with what you have tried and how it didn't work. Also please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `b0000000`. The extra zero's without a `1` holds no significance to the value

Comment: *I have 2 long long bytes*  I think you may be a bit confused; a byte is always 8 bits, but `long long` is typically 64 bits.  "long long bytes" doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it's only 8 bits wide, you don't need datatype `long long`. `uint8_t` is exactly 8 bits wide.

```
uint8_t bytes1 = b11111111;
uint8_t bytes2 = b10000000;
```

The result will be 16 bits wide, like `uint16_t`.

```
uint16_t result1 = (bytes2 << 8) | bytes1; // will be b1000000011111111
uint16_t result2 = (bytes1 << 8) | bytes2; // will be b1111111110000000
```

The `<<` operator shifts bits to the left, while the `|` operator does a binary OR operation (though in this case, a `+` would have worked just as well).

Comment: You may want to prefer the standard types `uint8_t` for 8 bits and `uint16_t` for 16 bit numbers.  The `unsigned char` is *at least* 8 bits, could be more.  An `unsigned short int` is at least 16 bits, could be 32.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use the LARGEINTEGER. For example:

```
LONGLONG byte1 = 10000000;
LONGLONG byte2 = 11111111;
LARGE_INTEGER largeInteger;
largeInteger.LowPart = byte1;
largeInteger.HighPart = byte2;
cout<< largeInteger.HighPart << largeInteger.LowPart;
```

or you  can use strings

```
LONGLONG llByte1 = 10000000;
LONGLONG llByte2 = 11111111;
string sBytes = std::to_string(llByte1);
sBytes.append(std::to_string(llByte2));
LONGLONG llBytes = atoll(sBytes.c_str());
cout << endl << "llBytes "<<llBytes << endl;
```

Comment: Strings?  -1 because that's just bad